# Style laravel form with bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am learning laravel.  I would like to add the following CSS atrributes:

```
<input type="text" class="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"  required="required" >
```

to the laravel form:

```
{{Form::text('first_name')}}
```

I googled, but I haven't been lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this:

```
{{Form::text('first_name','',array('class'=>'text','id'=>'first_name','placeholder'=>'First Name','required'))}}
```